# Javascript looping through object to find match pair url

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a reactjs project - where I have say an English url like "/en/how-it-works" and wish to loop through the json tree to find the position/child level at which this link is set -- and find its German matching pair.

So basically -- a function that is given the English url, returns the German url

so --

lng - return de
currenlang - en
pairUrl - /en/how-it-works

return /de/anleitung

or

lng - return en
currentlang de
pairUrl - /de/beliebte-projekte/bundle1

return /en/popular-projects/bundle1

//function

```
getLanguagePair (lng, currentLng, pairUrl) {
    //  'find url in json tree'
    console.log('linkTreeObject', linkTreeObject.langs)

    var obj = {}
    //find position in tree
    if(currentLng === 'de'){
      obj = linkTreeObject.langs[0].lines.menu
    } else {
      obj = linkTreeObject.langs[1].lines.menu
    }

    var pos = []
    for (var k in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
      if (obj[k].link === pairUrl) {
        pos[k]
      }
    }
    console.log('pos' , pos)

    if (lng === 'de') {
      return '/de/link'
    } else {
      return '/en/link'
    }
}
```

//json file

```
{
    "langs" : [
        {
            "lang"  : "de",
            "lines" : {
                "menu" : [
                    {
                        "title": "Anleitung",
                        "link": "/de/anleitung",
                        "children" : []
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Beliebte Projekte",
                        "link": "/de/beliebte-projekte",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle1",
                                "link"  : "/de/beliebte-projekte/bundle1"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle2",
                                "link"  : "/de/beliebte-projekte/bundle2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in"       : "Login"
            }
        },
        {
            "lang"  : "en",
            "lines" : {
                "menu" : [
                    {
                        "title": "How it works",
                        "link": "/en/how-it-works",
                        "children" : []
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Popular Projects",
                        "link": "/en/popular-projects",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle1",
                                "link"  : "/en/popular-projects/bundle1"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle2",
                                "link"  : "/en/popular-projects/bundle2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in"       : "Sign in"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through 'en' and 'de' simultaneously and use recursion since you have nested links. Here is my version. I already took out the 'en' and 'de' array and used them in the function.

```js
var obj ={
    "langs" : [
        {
            "lang"  : "de",
            "lines" : {
                "menu" : [
                    {
                        "title": "Anleitung",
                        "link": "/de/anleitung",
                        "children" : []
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Beliebte Projekte",
                        "link": "/de/beliebte-projekte",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle1",
                                "link"  : "/de/beliebte-projekte/bundle1"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle2",
                                "link"  : "/de/beliebte-projekte/bundle2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in"       : "Login"
            }
        },
        {
            "lang"  : "en",
            "lines" : {
                "menu" : [
                    {
                        "title": "How it works",
                        "link": "/en/how-it-works",
                        "children" : []
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Popular Projects",
                        "link": "/en/popular-projects",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle1",
                                "link"  : "/en/popular-projects/bundle1"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bundle2",
                                "link"  : "/en/popular-projects/bundle2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in"       : "Sign in"
            }
        }
    ]
};
var en = obj.langs[1].lines.menu;
var de = obj.langs[0].lines.menu;

function GetUrl(enUrl, enMenu, deMenu)
{
  var deUrl;
  for(var i = 0; i < enMenu.length; i++)
  {
   if(enMenu[i].link == enUrl)
    {
     deUrl = deMenu[i].link;
      break;
    }
    else
    {
     if(enMenu[i].children && enMenu[i].children.length > 0)
      {
       deUrl = GetUrl(enUrl,enMenu[i].children, deMenu[i].children )
      }
    }
  }
  
  return deUrl;
}

console.log(GetUrl("/en/how-it-works", en, de));
console.log(GetUrl("/en/popular-projects", en, de));
console.log(GetUrl("/en/popular-projects/bundle1", en, de));
console.log(GetUrl("/en/popular-projects/bundle2", en, de));
```

Comment: I think your's is a better example -- as I only go from parent to child -- didn't look at grand children - recursive - good idea

Comment: tried to put this into my example - but its failing -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/46/

Comment: You fiddle has different code than above. Is your code failing or the above code?

Comment: fixed it bud -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067246/javascript-menu-recursive-function-bugs/44068336?noredirect=1#comment75160857_44068336

Comment: -- recursive function was a bit borky

Comment: Ok. I see you modified so that you can treat both 'en' and 'de' as source and target but your main function and recursion expression is not returning anything. Glad it is fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: yeah cheers man -- I got other problems/questions --- routes/language params -- reinitialising jquery plugins? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072227/reactjs-404-page-and-language-param-missing-handling-issues and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069125/reactjs-routes-and-re-invoking-foundation-orbit-functions