# Javascript menu recursive function bugs

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

//current jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/45/

I am trying to loop through a json navigation tree - so that when a person goes to a particular page, it finds its alternative language counter-part.

//JSON

```
{
    "langs" : [
        {
            "lang"  : "de",
            "lines" : {
                "menu"    : [
                    {
                        "title"    : "Anleitung",
                        "link"     : "/de/anleitung"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Funktionen",
                        "link"     : "/de/funktionen"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Dienstleistungen",
                        "link"     : "/de/dienstleistungen",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Geistiges Eigentum",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/geistiges-eigentum"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Compliance",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/compliance"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Investment- und Beteiligungsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/beteiligungsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Mergers & Acquisitions",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/mergers-and-acquisitions"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Immobilienrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/immobilienrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Internet- und Datenschutzrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/internetrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Gesellschaftsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/gesellschaftsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Handelsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/handelsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Arbeitsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/arbeitsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bankrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/bankrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Vertragsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/vertragsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Wettbewerbsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/wettbewerbsrecht"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Beliebte Projekte",
                        "link"     : "/de/beliebte-projekte",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title"     : "Compliance",
                                "link"      : "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance",
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Haftungsrisiken für Geschäftsführern",
                                        "link" : "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/haftungsrisken-geschaeftsfuehrern"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Compliance-Prüfung KMU",
                                        "link" : "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/compliance-pruefung-kmu"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in" : "Login"
            }
        },
        {
            "lang"  : "en",
            "lines" : {
                "menu"    : [
                    {
                        "title"    : "How it works",
                        "link"     : "/en/how-it-works"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Features",
                        "link"     : "/en/features"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Services",
                        "link"     : "/en/services",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Intellectual property",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/intellectual-property"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Compliance",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/compliance"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Investment law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/investment-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Mergers & Acquisitions",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/mergers-and-acquisitions"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Real estate law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/real-estate-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Internet law and data privacy",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/internet-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Company law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/company-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Trade law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/trade-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Labour law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/labour-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bank law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/bank-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Contract law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/contract-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Competition law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/competition-law"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Popular Projects",
                        "link"     : "/en/popular-projects",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title"     : "Compliance",
                                "link"      : "/en/popular-projects/compliance",
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Haf eng",
                                        "link" : "/en/popular-projects/compliance/haf-eng"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Compliance eng",
                                        "link" : "/en/popular-projects/compliance/compliance-eng"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in" : "Sign in"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

my js functions

so in this case

imagine 
CURRENTLNG as en
CURRENTURL as /en/services

in fetchFooterUrls () - I want to return an array with ["/en/services", "/de/dienstleistungen"]
this code falls down in trying to get the 3rd level navigation counter parts
["/en/popular-projects/compliance/compliance-eng", "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/compliance-pruefung-kmu"]

```
  getUrl (pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
      if (obj[k].link === pairUrl) {
        if (currentLng === 'de') {
          return enMenu[k].link // get en link equivlant
        } else {
          return deMenu[k].link // get de link equivlant
        }
      } else {
        if (obj[k].hasOwnProperty('children') && obj[k].children.length > 0) continue
        this.getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu[k].children, deMenu[k].children, obj[k].children)
      }
    }
  }
  //
  getLanguagePair (currentLng, pairUrl) {
    //  'find url in json tree'
    var enMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[1].lines.menu
    var deMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[0].lines.menu

    let obj = {}
    // find position in tree
    if (currentLng === 'de') {
      obj = deMenu
    } else {
      obj = enMenu
    }

    return this.getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj)
  }

  fetchFooterUrls () {
    let deUrl = ''
    let enUrl = ''

    if (CURRENTLNG === 'de') {
      deUrl = CURRENTURL
      enUrl = this.getLanguagePair(CURRENTLNG, this.props.location.pathname)
    } else {
      enUrl = CURRENTURL
      deUrl = this.getLanguagePair(CURRENTLNG, this.props.location.pathname)
    }
    return [enUrl, deUrl]
  }
```

//tried to make this snippet - any moderators here to resolve?

```js
    var linkTreeObject ={
    "langs" : [
        {
            "lang"  : "de",
            "lines" : {
                "menu"    : [
                    {
                        "title"    : "Anleitung",
                        "link"     : "/de/anleitung"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Funktionen",
                        "link"     : "/de/funktionen"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Dienstleistungen",
                        "link"     : "/de/dienstleistungen",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Geistiges Eigentum",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/geistiges-eigentum"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Compliance",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/compliance"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Investment- und Beteiligungsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/beteiligungsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Mergers & Acquisitions",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/mergers-and-acquisitions"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Immobilienrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/immobilienrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Internet- und Datenschutzrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/internetrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Gesellschaftsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/gesellschaftsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Handelsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/handelsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Arbeitsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/arbeitsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bankrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/bankrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Vertragsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/vertragsrecht"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Wettbewerbsrecht",
                                "link"  : "/de/dienstleistungen/wettbewerbsrecht"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Beliebte Projekte",
                        "link"     : "/de/beliebte-projekte",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title"     : "Compliance",
                                "link"      : "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance",
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Haftungsrisiken für Geschäftsführern",
                                        "link" : "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/haftungsrisken-geschaeftsfuehrern"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Compliance-Prüfung KMU",
                                        "link" : "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/compliance-pruefung-kmu"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in" : "Login"
            }
        },
        {
            "lang"  : "en",
            "lines" : {
                "menu"    : [
                    {
                        "title"    : "How it works",
                        "link"     : "/en/how-it-works"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Features",
                        "link"     : "/en/features"
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Services",
                        "link"     : "/en/services",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title" : "Intellectual property",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/intellectual-property"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Compliance",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/compliance"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Investment law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/investment-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Mergers & Acquisitions",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/mergers-and-acquisitions"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Real estate law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/real-estate-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Internet law and data privacy",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/internet-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Company law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/company-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Trade law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/trade-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Labour law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/labour-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Bank law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/bank-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Contract law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/contract-law"
                            },
                            {
                                "title" : "Competition law",
                                "link"  : "/en/services/competition-law"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title"    : "Popular Projects",
                        "link"     : "/en/popular-projects",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "title"     : "Compliance",
                                "link"      : "/en/popular-projects/compliance",
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Haf eng",
                                        "link" : "/en/popular-projects/compliance/haf-eng"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title"      : "Compliance eng",
                                        "link" : "/en/popular-projects/compliance/compliance-eng"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sign_in" : "Sign in"
            }
        }
    ]
};



  getUrl (pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
      if (obj[k].link === pairUrl) {
        if (currentLng === 'de') {
          return enMenu[k].link // get en link equivlant
        } else {
          return deMenu[k].link // get de link equivlant
        }
      } else {
        if (obj[k].hasOwnProperty('children') && obj[k].children.length > 0) continue
        this.getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu[k].children, deMenu[k].children, obj[k].children)
      }
    }
  }
  //
  getLanguagePair (currentLng, pairUrl) {
    //  'find url in json tree'
    var enMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[1].lines.menu
    var deMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[0].lines.menu

    let obj = {}
    // find position in tree
    if (currentLng === 'de') {
      obj = deMenu
    } else {
      obj = enMenu
    }

    return this.getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj)
  }

console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/how-it-works"))
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute ES6 code in a ES5 browser?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/45/

Comment: @criz -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/50/

Comment: Gotcha! I'm about to answer you

Comment: I've tried breaking out of the loop -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the jsfiddle. You had errors related to the recursive function call in the else part.
http://jsfiddle.net/gaganshera/0ht35rpb/51/

Changed it to

```
 if (!obj[k].hasOwnProperty('children') || obj[k].children.length <= 0) continue;
 var ret = getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu[k].children, deMenu[k].children, obj[k].children);
 if(typeof ret != 'undefined') return ret;
```

```js
var linkTreeObject = {
  "langs": [{
    "lang": "de",
    "lines": {
      "menu": [{
        "title": "Anleitung",
        "link": "/de/anleitung"
      }, {
        "title": "Funktionen",
        "link": "/de/funktionen"
      }, {
        "title": "Dienstleistungen",
        "link": "/de/dienstleistungen",
        "children": [{
          "title": "Geistiges Eigentum",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/geistiges-eigentum"
        }, {
          "title": "Compliance",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/compliance"
        }, {
          "title": "Investment- und Beteiligungsrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/beteiligungsrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Mergers & Acquisitions",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/mergers-and-acquisitions"
        }, {
          "title": "Immobilienrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/immobilienrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Internet- und Datenschutzrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/internetrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Gesellschaftsrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/gesellschaftsrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Handelsrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/handelsrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Arbeitsrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/arbeitsrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Bankrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/bankrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Vertragsrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/vertragsrecht"
        }, {
          "title": "Wettbewerbsrecht",
          "link": "/de/dienstleistungen/wettbewerbsrecht"
        }]
      }, {
        "title": "Beliebte Projekte",
        "link": "/de/beliebte-projekte",
        "children": [{
          "title": "Compliance",
          "link": "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance",
          "children": [{
            "title": "Haftungsrisiken für Geschäftsführern",
            "link": "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/haftungsrisken-geschaeftsfuehrern"
          }, {
            "title": "Compliance-Prüfung KMU",
            "link": "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/compliance-pruefung-kmu"
          }]
        }]
      }],
      "sign_in": "Login"
    }
  }, {
    "lang": "en",
    "lines": {
      "menu": [{
        "title": "How it works",
        "link": "/en/how-it-works"
      }, {
        "title": "Features",
        "link": "/en/features"
      }, {
        "title": "Services",
        "link": "/en/services",
        "children": [{
          "title": "Intellectual property",
          "link": "/en/services/intellectual-property"
        }, {
          "title": "Compliance",
          "link": "/en/services/compliance"
        }, {
          "title": "Investment law",
          "link": "/en/services/investment-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Mergers & Acquisitions",
          "link": "/en/services/mergers-and-acquisitions"
        }, {
          "title": "Real estate law",
          "link": "/en/services/real-estate-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Internet law and data privacy",
          "link": "/en/services/internet-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Company law",
          "link": "/en/services/company-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Trade law",
          "link": "/en/services/trade-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Labour law",
          "link": "/en/services/labour-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Bank law",
          "link": "/en/services/bank-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Contract law",
          "link": "/en/services/contract-law"
        }, {
          "title": "Competition law",
          "link": "/en/services/competition-law"
        }]
      }, {
        "title": "Popular Projects",
        "link": "/en/popular-projects",
        "children": [{
          "title": "Compliance",
          "link": "/en/popular-projects/compliance",
          "children": [{
            "title": "Haf eng",
            "link": "/en/popular-projects/compliance/haf-eng"
          }, {
            "title": "Compliance eng",
            "link": "/en/popular-projects/compliance/compliance-eng"
          }]
        }]
      }],
      "sign_in": "Sign in"
    }
  }]
};

function getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
    if (obj[k].link === pairUrl) {
      if (currentLng === 'de') {
        return enMenu[k].link // get en link equivlant
      } else {
        return deMenu[k].link // get de link equivlant
      }
    } else {
      if (!obj[k].hasOwnProperty('children') || obj[k].children.length <= 0) continue;
      var ret = getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu[k].children, deMenu[k].children, obj[k].children);
      if(typeof ret != 'undefined') return ret;
    }
  }
}


function getLanguagePair(currentLng, pairUrl) {
  //  'find url in json tree'
  var enMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[1].lines.menu
  var deMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[0].lines.menu

  let obj = {}
    // find position in tree
  if (currentLng === 'de') {
    obj = deMenu
  } else {
    obj = enMenu
  }

  return getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj)
}

//works
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/how-it-works"))
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/popular-projects"))
console.log(getLanguagePair("de", "/de/anleitung"))
console.log(getLanguagePair("de", "/de/beliebte-projekte"))


//fail
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/services/compliance"))
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/popular-projects/compliance"))
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/popular-projects/compliance/compliance-eng"))
```

Comment: that fixed it -- is this the same as the other answer?

Comment: I wrote this before the other answer. I'm not sure if its the same

Comment: Well since the error was the same, I'm sure answer will be similar too :)

Comment: Thank you very much - you saved my bacon

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem in your recursive function. If you don't match the url at the *first function call*, you recursively call the function again but **you don't return it**.

```
function get_10_recursive(number){
  if(number>=10) return 10;
  else return get_10_recursive(number++);
}
```

In this example, if the number is smaller than 10, the function is recursively called until it encounter a *return* statement, after this, it retrace the stack and returns you the correct result. If you remove the return statement in the third line the code is executed as well but it returns the result **only of the first call**, which is undefined.

The problem in your code is that, if you place a *return* inside the for loop, the loop gets interrupted and you won't check the next strings, so you have to store the results of the function call in a temporary variable and return it only if it's truthy (aka it's not undefined).

Your getUrl function becomes like this:

```
function getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj[k].link === pairUrl) {
      if (currentLng === 'de') {
        return enMenu[k].link; // get en link equivlant
      } else {
        return deMenu[k].link; // get de link equivlant
      }
    } else {
      if (obj[k].hasOwnProperty('children')){
      var tmp =  getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu[k].children, deMenu[k].children, obj[k].children);
      if(tmp) return tmp; // check if it found the match successfully
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I remvoed the `if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue` because it was useless

Comment: is this the same as the other answer - the other answer fixed my problem

Comment: Thank you very much - you saved my bacon

Comment: Yes it is. Probably we wrote it at the same time